# How do I set the default language for the HtmlEditorExtender (AJAX Control Toolkit)?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, globalization, htmleditorextender

I'm trying to implement the HtmlEditorExtender from AJAX Control Toolkit.

Is it possible to change the control language? I'd want the language to be French. I have no problem at all changing the language of the CalendarExtender control, but it doesn't work at all with the HtmlEditorExtender. For example, the control still display English words like "Font" and "Size".

I have done everything that is suggested on the web to change the language.

The globalization culture is set in the web.config:

> globalization uiCulture="fr" culture="fr-CA" fileEncoding="utf-8"

I have a script manager in the master page and the EnableScriptGlobalization and EnableScriptLocalization are both set to true:

> asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
>               EnableScriptLocalization="true" ScriptMode="Release" AsyncPostBackTimeOut="0"/>

The culture is set on the page:

> %@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/FullForm.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Culture="fr-CA" UICulture="fr"
>       Inherits="LAC.WebApp.Management.Parameters.ParametersPage" meta:resourcekey="Page" CodeBehind="Parameters.aspx.cs" %

I have a "fr" folder in the bin folder with the AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll file in it.

I tried to run the application in release mode but it didn't change anything at all.

If you have any idea, please share it!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

HtmlEditorExtender is not localized. These strings are hardcoded.
So, the only option at the moment is to change it in source code and make a custom build.